# heroku not cacheing modules with yarn

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, yarnpkg, lerna

I am using [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), and now when I do my heroku deploys, they take an exceedingly long time (~3+ minutes)

I am suspect the issue is that the [heroku-node-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) is not caching/restoring correctly.  I know by default heroku cache/restores `node_modules`.  But I *think* yarn uses something like `/app/.cache/yarn/v4`

Does anyone have the magic sauce (configuration) to get this working.  Currently this is an unworkable solution.

---

More info, in case it is helpful:

My project structure is like:

```
/appRoot
  Procfile
  package.json
  learna.json  
  /packages
     /common
        package.json
     /api
        package.json
     /client
        package.json
```

```
➜ heroku buildpacks
=== my-project Buildpack URL
heroku/nodejs
```

```
➜ heroku run yarn cache dir
Running yarn cache dir on ⬢ my-project... up, run.7548 (Free)
/app/.cache/yarn/v4
```

Potential interesting package.json snippits

```
"heroku-postbuild": "lerna run build --scope common --scope api --scope server"
```

Procfile

```
web: yarn workspace server start
```